# Ajax file upload missing newlines

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to upload a text file via Ajax but the file received is just one long string with no line breaks.

Tried all the obvious things I can think of but just can't seem to get the received Ajax file to output CRLF properly.

Here is the client-side Javascript:

```
pagecontent = pagecontent.replace('\r', '\r\n');
var pageblob = new Blob([pagecontent], {type: "text/html"});
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Page", pageblob, pagename);
...
xmlhttp.send(formdata);
```

and this is the server-side PHP:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Page"]["tmp_name"], "FileName.txt";))
```

but the file saved is just one long string with no line breaks.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you turn regular text into a blob, and how do you send that, it seems like formdata is empty?

Comment: Sorry missed a line out when copying the code, now edited question to include that line.

Comment: If I don't use a blob how else do I send some HTML to a server and have it saved as a file?

Comment: By sending it as data to the server and saving it as a file? (aka, POST and `file_put_content`?)

Comment: Tried that but there seem to be size limits to sending data.  Sending files doesn't seem to suffer from the same limits.